# Auto-resize input box with rounded corners?

Tags: jquery, html, css, input

I created a text-box that looks like the image below, however I want it to resize as the user types like here:
http://jsbin.com/ahaxe

[image]

I think that it won't be a problem to insert the search image as a background and align it to the right, however I don't know how to do the rounded corners without using an image.

Thanks everybody :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
input {
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px; /* Saf3-4, iOS 1-3.2, Android <e;1.6 */
     -moz-border-radius: 12px; /* FF1-3.6 */
          border-radius: 12px; /* Opera 10.5, IE9, Saf5, Chrome, FF4, iOS 4, Android 2.1+ */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

its posible but its not work in IE
you can use css styles for this.
for example:
-moz-border-radius: 5px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
border-radius: 5px;

Answer (score 1):

Try faraz suggestion first, and if it doesn't work on IE, try adding another declaration, using the -ms- prefix, like this:

```
-ms-border-radius: 12px;
```

If it STILL doesn't work, you can try using CSS PIE to force css3 on IE: http://css3pie.com/

As for the resize solution, you'll probably find a better solution than my own, but you can try this:

```
<input onkeyup="if(this.value.length > 10) { this.style.width = this.offsetWidth + 20 + 'px' }" type="text" />
```

In this code, everytime the user type something on the box, the Javascript will check if the ammount of chars in the input is higher than 10. if Yes, then it'll grow 20px.

Change the values to your heart content, please. And good luck on your project.